# Show only important posts/updates on Google+

Tags: google-plus

Before Google+ changed recently, I remember there was a way to change the frequency of updates showing in my stream from those in my circles. I can no longer find that setting.

Is there a way I can reduce the number of updates from certain profiles, short of no longer following them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still adjust the volume of posts from people in your circles, and adjust how much of each you see.

From your home stream, select one of the circles shown on the top, or use the "More" item to pick a different circle:

[image: Circles bar]

Once you've selected a circle, you can click on the gear icon that will be in a box towards the right.

[image: Circle controls]

From here, you can check the box to say if you want it in the Home stream at all and, if you do, how much (roughly) you want to see. You can also use the Bell icon next to the gear to indicate if you want to receive notifications for posts in the circle.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, Prisoner! For whatever reason, I thought I was able to change post volume by individual people. Oops...